# Distribution function of the minimum of a random sample

Tags: probability

[image]

I would like to understand how one finds the distribution function of the minimum when one knows the distribution function of the maximum. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the CDF of the maximum, say $F_{X_\text{max}}(x)$, then from the first equation you have, the CDF of $X$ is given by $F_X(x) =\sqrt[n]{F_{\text{max}}(x)}$. Then from the second equation, the CDF of the minimum is given by $$F_{X_\text{min}}(x)= 1-(1-F_X(x))^n = 1-\left(1-\sqrt[n]{{F_{\text{max}}(x)}}\right)^n.$$